# How can I get a reference to an HttpResponse in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling a third-party library that takes a `System.Web.HttpResponse`. I see I have a `HttpResponseBase`, but not `HttpResponse` like in web forms.

Is there a way to get the `HttpResponse`? Using `MVC 3`.

**[Edit]** :
I'm trying to do this in a controller method. Also corrected casing.

Comment: Could you tell what is it that you are doing, for which you specifically need `HttpResponse`, instead of just a `HttpResponseBase`?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, he's calling a 3rd party library

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you need to interact with systems which take the non-mockable types, you can get access to the current HttpContext via the static property **System.Web.HttpContext.Current**.  The HttpResponse is just hanging off of there via the Response property.

Answer (score 11):

In mvc application you can use `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response`.This helped me for getting the `HttpResponse` in MVC Application.

Answer (score 5):

No, but your `HttpResponseBase` is probably an `HttpResponseWrapper` which contains an `HttpResponse` inside of it.  All the `HttpResponse` methods are accessible from the `HttpResponseBase`.

If you want access to the `HttpResponse`, then you could add a reference to it in `HttpContext.Items` in your `IHttpHandler` or somewhere earlier in the ASP.NET lifecycle.  The BeginRequest event would be a good point to do this.

Your `HttpContext.Items` references the same dictionary that `HttpContextBase.Items` references, so you will have access to all those items in MVC3

### To clarify,

It is an `HttpResponseWrapper`, but there is no public accessor for the `HttpResponse`.  So, there is not a directly accessible reference.  To make a directly accessible reference before the framework decides to start giving you the wrapper instead of the underlying reference, create an event handler for `HttpApplication.BeginRequest` event.  Your handler will have a reference to the `HttpContext` object.   Set `HttpContext.Items["HttpRequest"] = HttpContext.Request`.  Then in your controller you will be able to access the `HttpRequest` reference by `RequestContext.HttpContext.Items["HttpRequest"]`.

Comment: Thanks smartcaveman. It is indeed a HttpResponseWrapper. Added an edit to note I'm trying to do this in a controller method. I don't see where the wrapper contains a HttpResponse. Am I just missing something here? Not sure about your suggestion with the IHttpHandler either - I'm just doing this inside of a method.