# Is this still the recommended way of unit testing with API's that need HttpRequest and HttpResponse?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, httprequest, httpresponse, saml

Reference is to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313495/304832) and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313630/304832), which is voted but not marked. I don't like the marked answer because I need to unit test the controller.

Putting these into HttpRequest and HttpResponse during Application_BeginRequest smells a little, but I am dealing with a [ComponentSpace SAML 2 library](http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx) that takes these types as method args. Is there no better way to get access to these in MVC in a unit-testable way?

Here is what I am working with now. May refactor the .Items out into an extension method to encapsulate the cast and magic string, but this is the main idea:

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    // put the raw request in context items for use by ComponentSpace SAML lib
    Context.Items["HttpRequest"] = Context.Request;
    Context.Items["HttpResponse"] = Context.Response;
}
```

**in Service methods:**

```
// HttpContext is an instance of HttpContextBase
ServiceProvider.SendAuthnRequestByHTTPPost(
    HttpContext.Items["HttpResponse"] as HttpResponse, 
    authnRequest.Destination, authnRequestXml, relayState);

ServiceProvider.ReceiveSAMLResponseByHTTPPost(
    HttpContext.Items["HttpRequest"] as HttpRequest, 
    out samlResponseXml, out relayState);
```

Comment: _I don't like the marked answer_ why don't you start a bounty on that thread ?

Comment: @sh4nx0r, this way was cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the following line in your begin request

```
 Context.Items["HttpRequest"] = Context.Request;
```

If  your need is just the following line

```
 HttpContext.Items["HttpRequest"] as HttpRequest,
```

You can get the same affect by doing the following

```
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Comment: HttpContext is an instance of System.Web.HttpContext, but MVC deals with System.Web.HttpContextBase. I would prefer to unit test against the base implementations, not the old school implementations.

Comment: I am little confused when you are suggesting HttpContext.Items is unit testable but HttpContext.Current.Request is not

Comment: Our unit tests already mock HttpContextBase on the controllerContext. HttpContextBase.Request is an instance of HttpRequestBase, not HttpRequest. By putting the request in the HttpContext.Items collection, we can be sure that the HttpContextBase has a reference to it instead of an instance of HttpRequestBase. Are you suggesting we also mock HttpContext.Current for our unit tests? In addition to mocking controllerContext.HttpContext?

Comment: How about this HttpContextBase.ApplicationInstance.Context

Comment: Are you suggesting we mock HttpApplication?